# Tracking deliveries of orders - use trigger or derive from data?

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to update my purchase order database model.
A purchase order line may be received via multiple deliveries (e.g 100 ordered, arrives as 50 then 50).

**Goal** Tracking of outstanding orders (delivery of).

I'm currently struggling deciding between

1. Having a two tables directly modelling deliveries
2. Using triggers to achieve my goal.

**Question**: Are these two approaches equally valid?
If so, what implications / deciding factor between them.
If not, what is wrong with the approach.

Current model (simplified, relevant fields, tables only):

> *Purchase Order*
> id, required date
>
> *Purchase Order Line*
> id, purchase order id (fk), item quantity

### Two Tables

> *Delivery*
> id, purchase order id (fk), recieved date
>
> *Delivery Line*
> id, delivery id (fk), purchase order line id (fk), quantity recieved

To track outstanding order lines: sum *quantity recieved* for grouped by *purchase order line id* and compare to *line quantity* from the *Purchase Order Line* table.

### Triggers

> *Outstanding Purchase Order Line*
> id, purchase order line id (fk), quantity received, timestamp

On *Purchase Order Line* creation insert into *Outstanding Purchase Order Line* with quantity received of 0. Allow updates to *quantity received* less than *line quantity*. Allow deletion to model all being recieved.
Another trigger could track changes to *Outstanding Purchase Order Line* to get a sense of deliveries.

Comment: If you need to keep track of the data as deliveries are made, then you have no choice other than modelling the data that way. YOu can easily create a view if you want to simplify the total calculation.

Comment: @Andrew Allen: why would you need to have `deliveries` as aggregates of `delivery_lines`, why not just deliveries in the sense of "delivery lines" (single item deliveries)?

Comment: @GerdWagner This is why I’m struggling with the design process, too many ways to achieve the same thing. The reason I put deliveries into its own table is that I had the data item “deliveryDate” and potential subject identities of “Delivery” and “Delivery Line”. It seems more representative to put deliveryDate against Delivery . There might be say 30 items on an order which may arrive as 3 deliveries with 3 individual delivery notes (though no useful id on the paperwork).

Comment: If the delivery date is the only attribute of `deliveries`, this would not justify the overhead of managing another table, `deliveries`, in addition to `delivery_lines`. Rather, one would record the delivery date with the delivery lines.
Why do you call your second approach "Triggers"? A DB trigger is an Event-Condition-Action rule expressed in SQL with CREATE TRIGGER.